# How to set dropdown list selected text to an input using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have one `DropDownList` and one `Input`. What I want to achieve is to get the selected item text from `DropDownList` and set the text for the `Input` using jquery how can I do it.

Below is the code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.APIId, "APIId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @id = "apiid" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("APIId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.APIId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActionText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @id = "actiontext" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ActionText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActionText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to show the rendered HTML on browser. So that `id` or `class` of both `select` and `input` will be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below **[** *As i am unable to get id or class of your select and input boxes, so i am going with general approach* **]**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').val($('select option:selected').text());
});
```

Note:- jQuery library need to be added before this script code to make it working

A hard-coded example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').val($('select option:selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="1">Hey</option>
<option value="2">Check</option>
<option value="3">I</option>
<option value="4">am</option>
<option value="5" selected>Working Fine!</option>
</select>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: @KawashHaidari  glad to help you :):)

Comment: Done! I wasn't able to do it before because of the time.